# pd.get_dummies() with seperator and counts

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a data that looks like:

```
index stringColumn
0 A_B_B_B_C_C_D
1 A_B_C_D
2 B_C_D_E_F
3 A_E_F_F_F
```

I need to vectorize this stringColumn with counts, ending up with:

```
index A B C D E F
0 1 3 2 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
2 0 1 1 1 1 1
3 1 0 0 0 1 3
```

Therefore I need to do both: **counting** and **splitting**. Pandas str.get_dummies() function allows me to split the string using sep = '_' argument, however it does not count multiple values. pd.get_dummies() does the counting but it does not allow seperator.

My data is huge so I am looking for vectorized solutions, rather than for loops.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and `sum`:

```
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df['stringColumn'].str.split('_', expand=True), 
                    prefix='', prefix_sep='')
         .sum(level=0, axis=1))
```

Or count values per rows by [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), replace missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and convert to integers:

```
df1 = (df['stringColumn'].str.split('_', expand=True)
                         .apply(pd.value_counts, axis=1)
                         .fillna(0)  
                         .astype(int))
```

Or use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), performance should be very good:

```
from collections import Counter

df1 = (pd.DataFrame([Counter(x.split('_')) for x in df['stringColumn']])
         .fillna(0)
         .astype(int))
```

Or reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and count by [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = (df['stringColumn'].str.split('_', expand=True)
                         .stack()
                         .groupby(level=0)
                         .value_counts()
                         .unstack(fill_value=0))
```

---

```
print (df1)

   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  3  2  1  0  0
1  1  1  1  1  0  0
2  0  1  1  1  1  1
3  1  0  0  0  1  3
```

Comment: All works! Thanks. I want to let you know their runtime for small portion of my dataset, so that their complexity will be known:
1st solution: 15.3 sec
2nd solution: 1.66 sec
3rd solution: 44milisec!
4th solution: 1.28 sec